# netzke extjs 4 rails Grid not visible

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, extjs, netzke

I'm playing with ExtJs 4.x and netzke gems (netzke-basepack (0.7.4) netzke-core (0.7.5) netzke-persistence (0.1.0)

I've configured all correctly but of course, something must be wrong as I can't see my GridPane on the Browser.

If I inspect the source page, I can see the div correectly

And I can see the ExtJs code that netzke build, even the data fetched from my controller ...

But it's not visible on the browser.

What I'm missing ?

In the view application.html.erb I have correctly initialized it:

```
  <%= netzke_init %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

And the ExtJs javascript is symlinked correctly in the Public folder.

Code to call the Grid object:

```
        <%= netzke :expedient, :class_name => "Netzke::Basepack::GridPanel" , :model => "Expedient" %>
```

thanks,

### Edit:

Solved with ExtJS 4.0.x instead of ExtJS4.1.x

Comment: Can you post the code from the view where you embed the grid? Also, are you getting any Firebug error messages?

Comment: oh, now I see ... JS error: Netzke: Ext 4.0.x required. You have 4.1.x. ext.js:67
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'totalProperty' of undefined. I'm gonna change the ExtVersion and see. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with ExtJS 4.0.x instead of ExtJS4.1.x